# Bitcoin peer list

Tags: peers, peer-discovery

I noticed that a company I have connections with, has an asset (ip) that appears on this bitcoin peer list; http://pastebin.com/HTPjuJBt

In laymens terms, what is a peer list, and should I be concerned that said asset is compromised, or can any asset be chosen as a peer? In otherwords, if not explicitly 'allowed' by a company, can a node still appear in this list?

Answer (score 1):

#### What is a peer list?

It's a list of IP addresses or domain names running Bitcoin that you can give to your Bitcoin client with `addnode` configuration directives.

#### Does using these peer lists provide you with any benefit, over letting Bitcoin pick peers itself?

Probably not.

#### Can I be on a list without my permission?

It depends on who's writing the list.

#### Does having a node on one of these lists do you harm?

No. Your node will probably get more requests and connections, but Bitcoin can self-limit, so it's not a big deal.

#### How can I get a node removed from one of these lists?

Try asking the author of the list. The worst thing they can do is say no.

Alternately, you can shut down your Bitcoin node.

#### How'd they get my information?

You can look up any IP block and see who owns it through [ARIN's database](https://whois.arin.net/ui/). Of course, it may have been subleased or rented out to a third party.